# Calculating difference of sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry

Need to calculate $\sin 15-\cos 15$? In degrees. I got zero, but it is wrong. Though, it seems to me that I was solving correct, I was doing this was:
$\sin (45-30) - \cos (45-30) = ((\sqrt(6)-\sqrt(2)/4) - ((\sqrt(6)+\sqrt(2)/4) =0$

Comment: $(a-b)-(a+b) = a-b-a-b = -2b$

Answer (score 2):

You just did some algebra wrong.

$$\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

WA confirms http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2815%29-cos%2815%29

Answer (score 1):

The second last step

$$\frac{(\sqrt(6)-\sqrt(2)}4 - \frac{(\sqrt(6)+\sqrt(2)}4 = \frac{-2\sqrt2}4=\frac{-\sqrt{2}}2$$